# How do I update different objects in an array within the same query in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my mongoose schema:

```
const humanSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    person: [
        id: String,
        age: Number,
        sex: String,
        height: String
    ],
    employment: Boolean
});
```

This is my JSON body request I am trying to pass through postman as a PUT:

```
"humanID": "12345"
"personUpdate": {
  "humanAdultId": "6789",
  "age": 37,
  "sex": "male",
  "height": "5ft"
}
```

This is my 'human' database record that I am trying to update:

```
"id": "12345"
"person": [
{
  "id": "4321",
  "age": 21,
  "sex": "female",
  "height": "4ft"
},
{
  "id": "6789",
  "age": 35,
  "sex": "male",
  "height": "6ft"
},
{
  "id": "7654",
  "age": 27,
  "sex": "male",
  "height": "5ft"
}
]
```

I am trying to use the JSON body to update the 2nd object in the array. I want to update its values: age and height.

I want to do this by calling the Id of the overall record (humanID) and then the object Id (humanAdultId) to drill down further to the object I need. I have researched the $pull and $push route, but there has to be an easier way to do this. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a simple update with an arrayFilters !

See the documentation here for details : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/#specify-arrayfilters-for-array-update-operations

Something as follow should work :

```
humanCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id : myJson.humanId},
  {$set : {"person.$[myHumanAdult]" : myJson.person},
  {arrayFilters : [{"myHumanAdult.humanAdultId" : myJson.person.humanAdultId}]}
)
```

Comment: Sweet! I'll try this! Thank you!

Comment: Cool, don't forget to change the var with yours, and upvote or validate the answer if you feel that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Human.id` and `Human.person.id` property in your schema but your database documents show a `Human.humanID` and `Human.person.humanAdultId`. These need to have the same key, either `id` or `humanID` and `humanAdultId`.

Assuming your schema should be `humanID` and `humanAdultId` then based on your schema the `Human.humanID` and the `Human.person.humanAdultId` values are both of type `String`. As such you can find the `Human` that matches the `jsonData.humanID` and pick out the object from the `person` array that has a `person.humanAdultId` equal to `jsonData.person.humanAdultId` like so:

```js
const human = await Human.findOneAndUpdate(
{
   humanID: jsonData.humanID,
   person: {
       $elemMatch: {
          humanAdultId: jsonData.person.humanAdultId,
       }
   } 
},
{
   $set : {
      "person.$" : jsonData.person
   }
},
{new: true}
);
```

Comment: You are right, i wasn't calling my Id correctly within the example. I have updated accordingly. Ill try this out. Thank you!